# MySQL case error on where

Tags: mysql, case

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong with this MySQL `case` statement

```
    SELECT 
        CASE 
            forsale IS NOT NULL
            THEN 1
            ELSE 2
        END AS is_forsale
 FROM xcart_products 
        where  is_forsale=1
```

If I take out the `where` it works. I tried to replace `where` with `having` but no cigar.

Comment: @CodeCaster same error much simpler code

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the actual code and the full error.

Comment: You have a closing `)` without an opening bracket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least three problems.  First is the closing paren (which might just be a typo).  Second is the lack of `WHEN`.  Third is the use of the alias in the `where` clause, which is not allowed in SQL.  MySQL has an extension where you can use an alias in a `having` clause, so you could write this logic as:

```
SELECT  (CASE WHEN forsale IS NOT NULL
              THEN 1
              ELSE 2
         END) AS is_forsale
FROM xcart_products 
HAVING is_forsale = 1 ;
```

However, I think it is simpler to write:

```
SELECT 1 as is_forsale
FROM xcart_products
WHERE forsale IS NOT NULL;
```